# ocijdbc12.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform

Tags: oracle

I am getting this error message when I am trying to extract from the database to my local: cijdbc12.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform. I did install 64-bit SQLDevelope and gave path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java as someone in the previous question did similar things. I however still getting the same error message. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: The message suggests that you indeed installed 64 bit SQL Developer, but your system is not a 64 bit system. Maybe the CPU is, but the OS isn't.

Comment: But Intel, maybe? Or does `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` refer to a 32 bit Java runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody told you the Wrong Thing. On Windows `C:\Program Files (x86)` is the place where **32-bit** software is installed. [See this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/442246/why-does-64-bit-windows-need-a-separate-program-files-x86-folder). I suggest that you uninstall and re-install, and take all default settings. Best of luck.